# Prevent users turning off GPS on Motorola MC65 and MC67 Windows Mobile

Tags: motorola, windows-mobile-gps

I have a problem with the users of our Motorola hand held windows devices keep turning off their GPS.

I want to be able to prevent users from changing the GPS settings as the client we contract to requires the GPS location be recorded on the jobs we do for later finding and checking of the installed device.
It is also been useful when a field tech has installed someting in the wrong location as we have been able to find it again using the coordinates on the job photo.

Ideally I would like to lock the field users out of windows all together and the device to boot straight into the program they are supposed to be using and only have Windows accessible with the use of a password in the office.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at using **AppCenter** this program allows you to lockdown the device to only display "available" applications of your choice. It is password protected. For **Windows Mobile** The default password is *symbol*, this of course can be changed to any password of your choosing, and can be done in the **Administration menu**

Official download from the [Motorola Zebra Website](https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/US-EN/Mobile+Networks+RFID+and+BarCode+Scanners/Mobility+Software/Mobile+Application+Utilities/AppCenter_US-EN)

**EDIT:** Here is also a link to the [AppCenter Guide](http://www.barcodedatalink.com/media/pdf/AppCenter_Windows_Mobile_Administrator_Guide.pdf)